# Bash - How to make dynamic menu selection without eval

Tags: bash, docker, github, case, eval

I'm making a script for Docker environments, and I'm a bit stuck with a pigeonhole I've gotten myself into.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

# Variables
gituser="modem7"
gitrepo="docker-devenv"
gitfolder="Environments"
buildername="DockerDevBuilder"

# Colours
RED="\e[31m"
GREEN="\e[32m"
END="\e[0m"

echo "========================================="
printf "        Checking Dependencies\n"
echo "========================================="
printf "Checking if dependencies are installed...\n"
pkg_list=(docker jq)
tc() { set ${*,,} ; echo ${*^} ; }
for pkg in "${pkg_list[@]}"
do
  titlecase=$(tc $pkg)
  isinstalled=$(dpkg-query -l $pkg > /dev/null 2>&1)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
     then
       printf "~ $titlecase is...${GREEN}installed${END}\n"
     else
       printf "~ $titlecase is...${RED}not installed${END}\n"
       printf "Exiting Script. Install $pkg.\n"
       echo "========================================="
       exit
    fi
done
echo "========================================="

cat << "EOF" 
      ____             _             
     |  _ \  ___   ___| | _____ _ __ 
     | | | |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ | '__|
     | |_| | (_) | (__|   |  __| |   
     |____/ \___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|   
=========================================
EOF

PS3="Choose Option: "
dev_list=($(curl -fks https://api.github.com/repos/$gituser/$gitrepo/contents/$gitfolder | jq '. [] | .name' | tr -d '[]," '))
dev_list_array="${dev_list[*]}"
dev_list_array_pipe="${dev_list_array// /|}"
dev_list+=( "Prune" "Quit" )
echo -e "\nSelect an option:\n"
select dev_name in "${dev_list[@]}"; do
echo -e "\nYou've selected ${GREEN}${dev_name}${END}\n"
lowerdev=$(echo $dev_name | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
    eval "case \"$dev_name\" in
      "$dev_list_array_pipe")
          echo "Creating buildx builder..."
          if docker buildx create --use --name "$buildername" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
              echo ""
              echo "Builder $buildername created"
            else
              echo "Builder already created, using $buildername"
              docker buildx use "DockerDevBuilder"
              echo ""
          fi
          echo "Creating $dev_name Environment..."
          docker buildx build --rm=true --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 --load -t $lowerdev:dev https://github.com/$gituser/$gitrepo.git#:$gitfolder/$dev_name \
          && clear \
          && echo "=========================================" \
          && echo "Activating $dev_name Dev Environment..." \
          && echo "Press CTRL + D or type exit to leave the container" \
          && docker run --rm -it --name "$dev_name"Dev"$RANDOM" --hostname "$dev_name"Dev"$RANDOM" "$lowerdev:dev"
          break
          ;;
      "Prune")
          echo "Clearing Docker cache..."
          docker system prune -af
          echo ""
          echo "Removing Docker buildx builder..."
          if docker buildx rm "$buildername" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
              echo ""
              echo "Builder $buildername removed"
            else
              echo "Builder already removed, no action performed"
              echo ""
          fi          
          exec bash $0
          ;;
      "Quit")
          echo "Exiting script"
          exit
          ;;
       *)
          echo "invalid option $REPLY"
          ;;
    esac"
done

exit 0
```

I'm currently using "`eval "case \"$dev_name\" in`" but that seems problematic from what I've read.

It works, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to achieve what the results.

The choices are created from the folder names in [the repo](https://github.com/modem7/docker-devenv/tree/master/Environments), but I'm not quite sure how to get out of using eval. Am I worrying about something pointless?

Comment: What's the reason to use `eval` to begin with? The way that's quoted, it looks like most of the variables there get expanded _before_ the parsing step done by `eval`, meaning their contents would parsed as code, and if any of them come from outside the script, they could be used to inject code to be executed. Also, the syntax highlighting is off here (probably because of the single quote in the ASCII art), but if you remove the parts of the code before the `eval` line, you'll see the quoting is off in most of the `eval` part, leaving the variable expansions unquoted.

Comment: That is to say, if it works at all, I'm surprised it does.

Comment: Why can't you just use `case "$dev_name" in [...] esac`?

Comment: Totally agree with you @ilkkachu on the syntaxes, it's currently turned into one of those "it shouldn't work, and if you touch it, it breaks" situations. I'll give the eval part another look without the ascii nonsense and see where I get from there! If I remove the eval part and just leave in the case, it doesn't seem to register the choices as an array (bar "prune" and "quit")

Comment: @DopeGhoti - the reason for that is if I just do $dev_name, it starts building for the additional "prune" and "quit" options which becomes a problem. 

The "solution" there is to use the *) but then that leave me with no error correction.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this with the following changes:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail
shopt -s extglob

# Variables
gituser="modem7"
gitrepo="docker-devenv"
gitfolder="Environments"
buildername="DockerDevBuilder"
failuremsg=""

# Colours
RED="\e[31m"
GREEN="\e[32m"
END="\e[0m"

echo "========================================="
printf "        Checking Dependencies\n"
echo "========================================="
printf "Checking if dependencies are installed...\n"
pkg_list=(docker jq)
tc() { set ${*,,} ; echo ${*^} ; }
for pkg in "${pkg_list[@]}"
do
  titlecase=$(tc $pkg)
  isinstalled=$(dpkg-query -l $pkg > /dev/null 2>&1)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];
     then
       printf "~ $titlecase is...${GREEN}installed${END}\n"
     else
       printf "~ $titlecase is...${RED}not installed${END}\n"
       printf "Exiting Script. Install $pkg.\n"
       echo "========================================="
       exit
    fi
done
echo "========================================="

cat << "EOF" 
      ____             _             
     |  _ \  ___   ___| | _____ _ __ 
     | | | |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ | `__|
     | |_| | (_) | (__|   |  __| |   
     |____/ \___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|   
=========================================
EOF

ctrl_c () {
    echo -e "\nUser pressed Ctrl + C. Exiting script...\n"
    exit 1
}

# Trap CTRL+C
trap ctrl_c INT

PS3="Choose Option: "
dev_list=($(curl -fks https://api.github.com/repos/$gituser/$gitrepo/contents/$gitfolder | jq '. [] | .name' | tr -d '[]," '))
dev_env_options=${dev_list[0]};
for ((i=1; i<${#dev_list[@]}; i++)); do
        dev_env_options="$dev_env_options|${dev_list[i]}"
done
echo -e "\nSelect an option:\n"
select dev_name in "${dev_list[@]}" "Prune" "Quit"; do
echo -e "\nYou've selected ${GREEN}${dev_name}${END}\n"
lowerdev=$(echo $dev_name | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
    case $dev_name in
      +($dev_env_options))
          echo "Creating buildx builder..."
          if docker buildx create --use --name "$buildername" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
              echo -e "\nBuilder $buildername created..."
            else
              echo -e "Builder already created, using "$buildername"...\n"
              docker buildx use "$buildername"
          fi
          echo "Creating $dev_name Environment..."
          docker buildx build --rm=true --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 --load -t $lowerdev:dev https://github.com/$gituser/$gitrepo.git#:$gitfolder/$dev_name
          clear
          echo "========================================="
          echo "Activating $dev_name Dev Environment..."
          echo "Press CTRL + D or type exit to leave the container"
          docker run --rm -it --name "$dev_name"Dev"$RANDOM" --hostname "$dev_name"Dev"$RANDOM" "$lowerdev:dev" & dockerrun_pid=$!
          break
          ;;
      "Prune")
          echo "Clearing Docker cache..."
          docker system prune -af
          echo -e "\nRemoving Docker buildx builder..."
          if docker buildx rm "$buildername" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
              echo -e "\nBuilder $buildername removed"
            else
              echo -e "Builder already removed, no action performed\n"
          fi
          exec bash $0
          ;;
      "Quit")
          echo "Exiting script..."
          break
          ;;
       *)
          echo "Invalid option $REPLY"
          exec bash $0
          ;;
    esac
done

exit 0
```